Subject verb agreement - I as well as he is/am the culprit
I have read that in case of 'as well as' the verb agrees with the first subject but putting an 'am' sounds weird. Is it correct or is there more to that rule?

Are you sure you want to put yourself first? Anyway. that is super awkward either way.  We are both culprits.

Using "and" or "not only...but also" is definitely better here; and both should be followed by plural verb and predicate.

This sounds like the kind of rule you’ll find in books, but which doesn’t really apply very well to actual English usage. There may be some exceptions, but I cannot think of a single example or context where as well as sounds natural with two subjects that take different verb forms, unless it’s very parenthetical, e.g., “I (as well as my brother) live with my mother”. I think a better formulation of the rule would be that in the case of as well as, if the two subjects require different verb forms and there’s no significant pause, it is generally avoided altogether.

"I live with my mother, and so does my brother."

@JanusBahsJacquet Please can you post that as an Answer so I can upvote it. All the examples in the existing answers sound about as realistic to me as "up with which I will not put".

@IMSoP Done, with a bit more detail.

@IMSoP, "up with which putting I will not do" :)

@abhay Weird it may sound but you have to follow the rules, especially if you are appearing for an examination. Even VOA Learning English suggests this answer. The second subject is not considered and it is put inside commas. I, as well as he, am the culprit is the only right answer.. In speech you can use and if you don't like the look of it.

@JamesMathai Who is "you", and who gets to make "the rules"? I think it's perfectly reasonable for native speakers of a language to call a rule "wrong", even if it appears on an exam syllabus; and it's a useful service to learners to tell them so, even if they also need to memorise the rule to pass an exam. That's why I included the Churchill quote: an exam might require you to torture language like that if it's trying to make you learn "rules", but actually learning English requires learning why that sentence is ridiculous.

As well as he is an interruption and doesn't affect the form of BE for the subject I here: I am.
To avoid the weirdness, we could say We both are culprits or Both he and I are culprits.

This is not what vetted grammar sources like CaGEL say about his. See the wiki post by F.E below!!!

OP's query on "Subject verb agreement:

I have read that in case of 'as well as' the verb agrees with the first subject but putting an 'am' sounds weird. Is it correct or is there more to that rule?

I. Subject verb agreement rules:
As per the subject verb agreement:

When two subjects are joined by these words the verb agrees with the first subject: - "as well as", "like", "unlike" "in addition to", "along with", "with", "together with".
When two subjects are joined with these words the verb agrees with the second subject. - "or", "nor", "either", "neither"

II. Subject verb agreement for "as well as":
Ref. learningenglish.voanews.com

Normally, if a subject is singular, we use a singular verb. If the subject is plural, then we use the plural form of the verb. But, in many cases, having “as well as” after the subject does not make the subject plural.
My cat, as well as my dogs, plays outside in the yard every day.
If you want to include the noun “my dogs” in the subject, use “and.” Then the subject will be plural.
My cat and my dogs play outside in the yard every day.

As per the Subject verb agreement all the sentences below are grammatically correct. If it sounds awkward in normal speech, you have the choice to join with other words as explained above.

I, as well as he, am guilty.
He, as well as I, is guilty.
You, as well as he, are guilty.
He, as well as you, is guilty.


The other answers have provided sources for the claim that when two subjects are coordinated with as well as, the verb never agrees with just the second one. This much is definitely true.
Out of them, @ishtar’s answer does the better job, since it makes it clear that as well as can be used both to introduce a parenthetical addition and as a more regular coordinator, similar to and, and that this makes a difference in the verbal agreement:

parenthetical as well as follows the agreement of the first subject (since that is the ‘real’ subject, the other being part of an ‘extra’ element that doesn’t count as an integral part of the sentence)
coordinative as well as triggers the same kind of agreement that and would, which will generally be plural agreement (since two coordinated subjects normally count as plural)

However, there is one aspect the other answers fail to mention: if the two subjects trigger different agreements, parenthetical as well as is generally avoided altogether, and (1) above only really applies when the two subjects would trigger the same agreement to begin with – in which case, of course, it’s sort of a moot point whether it’s the first or the second subject’s agreement that’s used.
So the rule that the first subject’s agreement ‘wins’ may be correct, but it has all the markings of a ‘book rule’, something that you’ll read in grammar books, but which is never actually used in real language use.
In other words, these coordinative uses are reasonably normal (albeit a bit stuffy-sounding):

He as well as I are the culprits.
I as well as he are the culprits.
More natural: Both he and I are the culprits.

But these parenthetical uses range from being quite awkward and clumsy (marked with ?) to being downright ungrammatical and ridiculous-sounding (marked with *), and you’re very unlikely to hear a native speaker produce any of them naturally:

?I, as well as he, am the culprit.
?He, as well as I, is the culprit.
*I, as well as he, is the culprit.
*He, as well as I, am the culprit.
More natural: I’m the culprit as well as him [or as well as he is]. / He’s the culprit, as well as me [or as well as I am].

The only time when parenthetical as well as might be used with subjects that trigger different agreements is if the parenthetic nature is made extremely explicit, by adding a very clear pause and a very clear change in intonation. Doing this has the added effect of making the entire statement feel like an addendum to something previous; for example:

I – as well as my mother, of course – am a great fan of David Bowie.

This would be natural enough for me to say if the previous context had been talking about my mother and her taste in music. But I cannot really conceive of a context where “I, as well as he, am the culprit” would make sense and sound natural.

There is very similar question on our sister site, English language and Usage:

What is the correct verb that follows "as well as?"

An excellent poster from ELL, F.E. answered the question. What he showed was that there is more than one way to answer the question! Here is his answer post from EL&U:



Which of the following sentences is correct?

He as well as they are in the wrong.

He as well as they is in the wrong.



Sometimes the expression "as well as" behaves like the coordinator and, and sometimes it doesn't.
In your example(s)--and because delimiting commas aren't used--perhaps the preferred interpretation could be that the expression "as well as" is behaving as the coordinator and. And so, perhaps your version #1 could be the more natural one:



He as well as they are in the wrong.



Here, the plural verb "are" agrees in number to the notional plural subject. Compare to "He as well as she are in the wrong", "Tom as well as Sue are in the wrong".
A decent usage dictionary will usually have info related to this topic. For instance, in my copy of the Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage, it has the entry "as well as" on pages 101-2, where it discusses the coordinator usage of that expression.
For related info from a vetted grammar source, there's the 2002 CGEL, pages 1316-7:

As well as
. . . There is also an idiomatic use meaning approximately "and, in addition to", illustrated in:
[70]

i. a. She [means what she says] [as well as says what she means].

i. b. [Abstraction] [as well as impressionism] were Russian inventions.

i. c. [Both increasing ewe liveweight,] [as well as liveweight at mating,] influence ovulation rate and lambing performance.


. . .
In [i] as well as behaves like the coordinator and. In [i.a] it links two finite VPs, a property characteristic of coordinators: cf. property (c) of &2.1. . . .
In [i.b] the form were indicates that the subject NP is plural, just like abstraction and impressionism.
And in [i.c] we have not only such plural agreement, but also a correlative pairing of both with as well as instead of the usual and.

In CGEL, there are also examples of singular verb usage, e.g. [70.ii.a] "Beauty as well as love is redemptive."
In conclusion, the answer probably comes down to whichever version you prefer, which could come down to the context, and/or the style guide of the publisher.
Note that CGEL is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL).
